# Vector with dynamically allocated memory cannot delete the last

Tags: c++, vector, new-operator, delete-operator

In my code I have a vector that holds integers. Using the first loop I create 100 new integers and push them on the vector. The next loop then deletes all the dynamically allocated integers with the exception of the last, because the deletion of the last integer causes the error and returns 0xc0000005. Why does my program crash with the deletion of the last integer?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> list;

    cout << list.size() << endl;

    int i = 0;
    while(i!=100)
    {
        list.push_back(*(new int(12)));
        i++;
    }

    cout << list.size() << endl;

    i=0;
    while(i!=99)
    {
        delete &list.back();
        list.pop_back();
        i++;
    }
/*
    delete &list.back();

    list.pop_back();
*/
    cout << list.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you create a vector<int>, std::vector will handle the allocation.  You don't need to allocate the integers yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not doing what you think you are. What are pushed in to the vector are **not dynamically allocated `ints` but a copy of the values of the dynamically allocated `ints`**.

So on this part

```
list.push_back(*(new int(12)));
```

you create a new `int` on heap with value 12 and then copy its **value** in to the vector. So you can not do

```
delete &list.back();
```

on the `ints`.

That fact tat you had to take the address of the value should tell you that it is actually not a pointer in there.

---

If you want to store the pointers then use

```
vector<int*> list;
          ^^
```

and push like

```
list.push_back(new int(12));
```

and you can delete as

```
delete list.back();
```

---

**However just don't do it**. No need to dynamically allocate `int`s. use

```
vector<int> list;
list.push_back(12);
// Nothing needs to be deleted.
```

Comment: "However just don't do it." indeed. If it is really necessary for your vector to contain pointers to integers then use an appropriate smart pointer; or use std::vector<std::vector<Type>> instead. Mixing pointers and STL is a horrific habit.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explanation makes a lot of sense and I understand where I went wrong. Thanks, again!

Comment: @DavidBos Glad I could Help. Take it easy on the pointers and dynamic allocation :)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `list.push_back(*new int(12));`you just add the number 12 to the vector, after this operation `&vector.back()` is not equal to the address `new int(12)` returned. You can move `new int(12)` to previous line, store the result and verify yourself.

I wonder why it doesn't crash on the first iteration of the deletion loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even trying to use new and delete! If you had a vector of *pointers* there might be some reason to use new, but you have a vectors of ints. So just push ints onto your vector.

```
while(i!=100)
{
    list.push_back(12);
    i++;
}

cout << list.size() << endl;
list.clear();
```

It amazes me the way newbies are addicted to new, delete, pointers etc. C++ is easier than that!

Comment: Yes, I realize that now. I was overthinking things enormously :P